# What is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 H_k}$?

Tags: asymptotics

According to [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/66638/2875), $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 H_k}$ is approximately 1.33275. How?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Note that you copied that wrong. The answer makes this claim for $\sum H_k \cdot 1/k^2$. (Not that the typesetting is very clear about that!)

Comment: Try [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%201%2F(k%5E2*harmonic(k))%20for%20k%3D1..infinity).

Comment: There is an actual question hiding here: how do we estimate the sum of an infinite series to a given number of decimal digits?

Answer (score 1):

To get a rough idea, you just use a spreadsheet and add the first 1000 numbers. The result is about 1.33263641018923. With no idea if that is a good or bad approximation without a proof, but any such sum is a lower bound.

Obviously $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 H_k} = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k^2 H_k} + \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 H_k}$ for every m. We can calculate the first sum for moderately large m. We can then replace the second sum with a slightly larger one that we can calculate exactly:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 H_k} ≤ \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k^2 H_k} + \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 H_{m+1}} = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k^2 H_k} +  \frac{1}{H_{m+1}}\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$

The sum of 1/k^2 for k ≥ m+1 is calculated by starting with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = π^2 / 6$ and subtracting the first m reciprocal squares. For m = 1000 this gives an upper bound of 1.332,769,917,72819.

Comment: You can substantially improve on your upper bound using the inequality $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty 1/k^2 \leq \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty 1/k(k-1) = 1/m$.